# Dual cooling system for lithium ion battery pack

Tags: sensor, temperature

My project is about making a system to control the temperature inside the battery pack for an electric car. Fan / blower will turn on automatically if the sensor reads a temperature more than 35°C.

For this project, I need to choose the temperature sensor, whether thermocouple and thermistor. Any suggestions for the sensor and reason for choosing that would be helpful .

Comment: I don't see a question here. Perhaps consider editing and giving us what you've read, which way you're leaning and why.

Answer (score 1):

You could employ a network of redundant thermistor or other silicon based sensors situated around each of the batteries for the same materials cost as a single thermocouple, offering better accuracy and redundancy for the controller.
One other advantage of using out of the box silicon sensors is that they will likely offer a part number that already is rated for automotive applications, which is something worth considering for this design. Using a self contained sensor with a digital interface will also greatly mitigate issues that could be due to electrical noise or other practical areas of pain.

Answer (score -1):

Since matrix arrangements of batteries can create current "hogging" from lower impedance or lower charged cells, it is wise to monitor every cell and modulate the impedance with controllable shunts such as how I believe it is done in the Tesla auto design with 89? MOSFETS.  In this case thermocouples would be very expensive and thermisters can be 1% as are calibrated diode thermistors and very inexpensive. There is also a $1 thermal sensor IC solution on I2C bus.

Battery terminal temperatures depend on how much power dissipation is expected in each cell and its thermal resistance  ['K/W] to outside case, the aging factors on each cell and the differential aging factors and differential ESR and temperature rise may dictate how many cell voltage and cell temperature sensors you wish to use for smart cell management.

If you just want to to lower the ambient temperature then you may need more than just a fan, but a heat transport solution with fan.

Comment: Your answer is very confusing and contains lots of off-topic statements..